# Turn a function into a class in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, class

I have the following columns in my dataframe:

[image]

I added a new column to my dataframe so that it displays the name of the winner:

*If Team 1 goals > Team 2 goals, then the winner is Team 1 name.*

I used the following function and it works as expected:

```
def winner(row):
    if row['Team 1 goals'] > row['Team 2 goals']:
        return row['Team 1 name']
    elif row['Team 2 goals'] > row['Team 1 goals']:
        return row['Team 2 name']
    else:
        return 'Draw'

df['Winner of The Game'] = df.apply(winner, axis=1)
```

But then, I need to use this block of code as a class.

I use a class like this:

```
class winner:
    def __init__(self,row):
        self.row=row
        def winner(row):
            if self.row['Team 1 goals'] > self.row['Team 2 goals']:
                return  obj['Team 1 name']
            elif self.row['Team 2 goals'] > self.row['Team 1 goals']:
                return self.row['Team 2 name']
            else:
                return 'Draw'
```

At that point, the final output in my table will be like this (it doesn't display the correct name of the winner team):

[image]

How should I fix my class so that it shows the correct winner team's name?

Comment: You are applying the class and not the method inside it. use `df.apply(winner.winner)` Also your indentation is off hope that is correct in your code.

Comment: like this?
wc['Winner of The Game'] = wc.apply(winner.winner, axis=1)

I get this error then:

AttributeError: type object 'winner' has no attribute 'winner'

Comment: you have wrong indentations - you have `def winner` inside `def __init__` - so it can't find `winner.winner` Line `def winner` should have the same indentation as `def __init__`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your indentation is off.
2. You are calling the class object

Here is simpler version of your code block

```
class winner:
    def __init__(self,row):
        self.row=row
    def winner(row):
        return 'Draw'
df = pd.DataFrame([[1],[2],[3]],columns=['a'])

df['new']= df.apply(winner.winner,axis=1)
df
```